# Linq SelectMany generates empty list

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `StudentsList` of over 100 students.

```
   public class Student
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        private string _subject;
        public string Subject
        {
            get { return _subject; }
            set { _subject = value; }
        }

        private int _age;
        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age= value; }
        }
    }
```

When I type a subject, I want to make a separate `List<string>` with names of all students enrolled for that subject.

**I tried-**

```
    List<string> results= new List<string>();

    results = students.Where(x => x.Subject.Contains("Science")).SelectMany(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

When I tried this Linq query, it generated Null results. Nothing in the list.

[image: Expected Results]

Comment: `SelectMany` is incorrect here. Use `Select` instead.

Comment: FYI, calculated fields like `Age` should not be stored. Instead, the start date (like `Birthday` for a person) should be stored, and then `Age` should be calculated based on the current date.

Comment: I'm wondering how you got anything, null or not, out of that.  `SelectMany` is iterating the `char`s in each `Name` so it would be returning `IEnumerable<char>`, thus you're ultimately trying to assign a `List<char>` to `results` (which is declared as `List<string>`). That's a compiler error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `.Select()` instead of `.SelectMany()`

```
   results = students
               .Where(x => x.Subject.Contains("Science"))  //Filter by Subject
               .Select(x => x.Name)              //Select only Name. 
               .ToList();                        //Convert to List
```

---

When do we use [`.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1)?

> Let us consider, we have `List<School>`, in each school we have
> `List<Student>` and we want all science students from all schools, that
> time we need to flatten Students list from list of school.

When do we use [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netcore-3.1)?

> When we want to iterate over students list and generate
> new form i.e reading only name out of it.

Answer (score 3):

You're checking if the subject string contains the substring "Science", not checking for students with a subject of "Science" like it seems you want. Your code should be like this instead;

```
var results = students.Where(s => s.Subject == "Science").ToList();
```

EDIT: If you want just the names instead of the `Student` objects, you can just add a `Select()` to the query:

```
var names = students
               .Where(s => s.Subject == "Science")
               .Select(s => s.Name)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: OP is asking for a List<string> that are is a mapping of the students' names, not instances of Student.

Comment: @Luke I've added an alternate query for that.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you actually want to use `Select()` rather than `SelectMany()`. The former will project a single property to a new Collection.

Try this:

```cs
results = students.Where(x => x.Subject.Contains("Science")).Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```